# TYPO3 TypoScript active rootNode in Webseite in Menu

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I've got a TYPO3 page (6.2.31) and want to make the root node actvie in typoscript. roodnode is the globe.

my typoscript looks like this at the moment:

```
NAVIMAIN = HMENU
NAVIMAIN.entryLevel = 0
#NAVIMAIN.excludeUidList = 

NAVIMAIN {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="sf-menu">|</ul>
        noBlur = 1

        NO = 1
        NO.ATagTitle.field = title
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  

        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"> |</li>  

    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        expAll = 1
        maxItems = 10
        wrap = <div class="sf-mega">|</div>
        NO = 1
        NO {
          ATagTitle.field = title
          wrapItemAndSub = <div class="sf-mega-section">|</div>
          stdWrap.wrap = |
          ATagParams =  class="headermega"
          stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
          doNotLinkIt = 0
        }
    }

    3 = TMENU
    3 {
        expAll = 1
        maxItems = 20
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
          ATagTitle.field = title
          linkWrap = <li>|</li>
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
          wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
          ATagParams =  class="active"
        }
    }
    #4 < .3

   }
```

All other pages are marked as aktive. only the rood node not.

[image]

root node is the globe, there is one link (third) that redirects to root node

Whats my problem?
Thanks

Comment: can you please add an screenshot of your pagetree (I assume there are some shortcuts concerning the root-/home-page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the menu item (which links to your root node) stated as active.
With the TypoScript option `alwaysActivePIDlist` and a condition you can do that.

Example:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = <page uid of root node>]
    NAVIMAIN.alwaysActivePIDlist = <page uid you want to set as active>
[global]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not have any effect. tried this: `[globalVar = TSFE:id=1]
    NAVIMAIN.alwaysActivePIDlist = [1]
[global]

[globalVar = TSFE:id=1]
    NAVIMAIN.alwaysActivePIDlist = [60]
[global]`

1 is root node and 60 is a shortcut

Comment: do not include page-ids in brackets. (bad meta-syntax) . you need something like (attention: no linebreaks available in comments!) `[globalVar = TSFE:id = 1] \n NAVIMAIN.alwaysActivePIDlist = 60 \n [global]`

Comment: also tried it without brackets. `[globalVar = TSFE:id=1]
    NAVIMAIN.alwaysActivePIDlist = 1
[global]

[globalVar = TSFE:id=1]
    NAVIMAIN.alwaysActivePIDlist = 60
[global]`

Comment: do you have some hints for me?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ do you have aditional hints for me?

Comment: sorry, lost notification of this. now see [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932881/typo3-mark-root-page-as-active)